# How can I get the second value in a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

So I've got an Object namely:

test:{price: 9, qty:1}

How can I loop through this object and only get the second value namely the qty?

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
test:{price: 9, qty:1}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div v-for="(value, key, index) in test>
   {{ value[1] }} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `test` is an object and you want to access just a single property, so there is no need to loop here you can simply access the object property using `.` dot notation like:

```
<div>
   {{ test.qty }} 
</div>
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: {
      price: 9,
      qty: 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <div class="card p-2">
    Qty: {{ test.qty }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for) says: `Using v-if and v-for together is not recommended.`